# User adding new words to a string array which is used by a list (App stops working)

Tags: java, android, string, list, user-interface

I have made a small app which is a dictionary. It pops up the meaning when a word from the list is selected using toast. I added a feature that will allow user to add new word and its definition which is not working.
The following is the code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private String[] words = {
        "Ankit Rath","Mediocre","Idiot","Legend"

};

private String[] defn = {
        "Creator of this App!","Android Development","Developer","Ankit Rath"

};

private String d="";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    run();


}
**public void run(){
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.li);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adap = new ArrayAdapter<>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            words
    );
    list.setAdapter(adap);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String de = defn[i];
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),de,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}**


**public void add(View view) {
    EditText txtw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.t1);
    String ndef = txtw.getText().toString();
    defn[defn.length] = ndef;
    EditText txtd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.t2);
    String nword = txtd.getText().toString();
    words[words.length] = nword;
    run();
}**

public void reset1(View view) {
    EditText t1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.t1);
    t1.setText("");

}
public void reset2(View view) {
    EditText t2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.t2);
    t2.setText("");

}
}
```

This is the code. The important codes are marked with **. The following is the preview : 
[image]

I hope all this is enough to find solution. Please help.

Comment: You say "it's not working"...but what is the behavior ? Do you have check in Debug mode ?

Comment: Please post the stack trace of the crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`defn[defn.length] = ndef;` would result in `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, since you are trying to access an index beyond the array size.

You should use a `List` instead.

Similarly, use a `List` for `words`.

Next, you don't need to create a new `ListView` or `Adapter` every time your data changes. Simply use `adap.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

### EDIT

Your program should be:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private List<String> words;

    private List<String> defn;

    private String d="";
    ListView list;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adap;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        words = new ArrayList<>();
        words.add("Ankit Rath");
        words.add("Mediocre");
        words.add("Idiot");
        words.add("Legend");

        defn = new ArrayList<>();
        defn.add("Creator of this App!");
        defn.add("Android Development");
        defn.add("Developer");
        defn.add("Ankit Rath");

        run();
    }

    public void run(){
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.li);
        adap = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                words
        );
        list.setAdapter(adap);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String de = defn.get(i);

                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),de,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }


    public void add(View view) {
        EditText txtw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.t1);
        String ndef = txtw.getText().toString();
        defn.add(ndef);
        EditText txtd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.t2);
        String nword = txtd.getText().toString();
        words.add(nword);
        adap.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void reset1(View view) {
        EditText t1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.t1);
        t1.setText("");

    }
    public void reset2(View view) {
        EditText t2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.t2);
        t2.setText("");

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Specially for that setchanged method :D

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private  ArrayList<String> words=new ArrayList<String>();
    private  ArrayList<String> defn=new ArrayList<String>();

/*private String[] words = {
        "Ankit Rath","Mediocre","Idiot","Legend"

};*/

/*private String[] defn = {
        "Creator of this App!","Android Development","Developer","Ankit Rath"

};*/

private String d="";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    words.add("Ankit Rath");
    words.add("Mediocre");
    words.add("Idiot");
    words.add("Legend");

    defn.add("Creator of this App!");
    defn.add("Android Development");
    defn.add("Developer");
    defn.add("Ankit Rath");


    run();


}
public void run(){
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.li);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adap = new ArrayAdapter<>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            words
    );
    list.setAdapter(adap);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String de = defn.get(i);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),de,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}


public void add(View view) {
    EditText txtw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.t1);
    String ndef = txtw.getText().toString();
    defn.add(ndef);
    EditText txtd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.t2);
    String nword = txtd.getText().toString();
    words.add(nword);
    run();
}

public void reset1(View view) {
    EditText t1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.t1);
    t1.setText("");

}
public void reset2(View view) {
    EditText t2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.t2);
    t2.setText("");

}
}
```

Use array list so you can add item at runtime. change your code as above.
You can't add items to simple array it's size is fixed in compile time you can't add new items to array at runtime.

Comment: Great This works as well but the other answer had datasetchanged method which is more efficient. Thanks a lot!

Comment: i haave done it but my repo is below 15 so it wont be displayed publicly i guess...

Comment: Okay i understood, i am glad that your problem is resolved